# How to get the basic math for neural networks?

Tags: math, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I have recently decided to start learning about artificial intelligence, and specifically about neural networks, because I believe it would allow me to solve new problems I am currently unable to tackle.

As a first step, I would like to be able to write a simple neural network that would allow me to recognize handwritten digits (using the MNIST dataset), and I would rather like to be able to do that in the next few weeks/months.

I have found many resources for beginners, some of which seem really good (like this one : http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html). I have read the beginning of 5-6 books about neural networks, but the problem I always have is that after some point, I get lost in the explanation, due to my lack of knowledge in math.

In the linked tutorial for example, I have trouble with the following symbols : ∇, ∂, →. More generally, I stumble upon mathematical notation : the constants, which I don't know but that authors assume the reader knows about, and special symbols.

So here comes my question : what kind of mathematics do I need in order to get me quickly started into neural networks, and that would allow me to read without too much trouble one of those great books/tutorials I found. I have some very basic notions in linear algebra, but that's about it.

Comment: https://www.coursera.org/courses/?query=machine%20learning&languages=en&availability=selfPaced%2CwithinOneMonth

Comment: look for a book on calculus algorithms for computer code. So even without understanding it deeply, you know when you see a certain symbol (which is usually a "method" or subroutine), you'll know which computer function to call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a grounding in calculus in order to understand the math underlying basic neural network training.  There's really no way around it -- most neural network training is some variant on "gradient descent" optimization.  The gradient is a form of derivative;  in order to find the gradient, you must take the derivative.

If you're looking for a bare minimum, then you can get by with understanding derivatives, rather than pushing on to integral calculus -- e.g., two of the symbols in your question stand for taking a particular kind of derivative.

Linear algebra is important as well, and it is good that you have some.  You don't really need anything fancy in order to understand basic neural network stuff, but knowing what a vector is, how matrix multiplication works and why, is also essential.

Comment: Thanks very much. So I will look into calculus. What would be your advice for the next step ? Maybe probability ?

Comment: Depends on where you're starting from; most people think calculus is plenty!  You shouldn't need probability to do basic neural network stuff, though, but that and basic Bayesian statistics might be helpful (though not essential) for recognition problems.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just go out and say it: Have you looked for a course which is less mathematical?

While you certainly need the advanced math to fully master the topic, you could find an introductory course which takes more of an overview of the field, along with some specific, hands-on practical working examples. That's how I learned Python (thanks, YouTube!)

**EDIT:**

@sputnik

> What kind of advanced math do you think is needed ?

Very simply, I think you *don't*.

**I can't recommend highly enough** the on-line [visual introduction to machine learning](http://www.r2d3.us/visual-intro-to-machine-learning-part-1/).

> I have recently decided to start learning about artificial intelligence, and specifically about neural networks, because I believe it would allow me to solve new problems I am currently unable to tackle.

The main point to the primer I referred to is that they start you off on Decision Trees. This is reminiscent of the Expert Systems employed half-a-century ago, and serve as an excellent narrative for someone just getting to know the subject.

Tree based models are famously the **most common technique among Kaggle competition winners**, [XGB trees](http://dmlc.cs.washington.edu/xgboost.html)* in particular. **Only next come Neural Nets**, so why settle for second best? ;-)

[image: [Airbnb New User Bookings, Winner's Interview: 2nd place, Keiichi Kuroyanagi (@Keiku)](http://blog.kaggle.com/2016/03/17/airbnb-new-user-bookings-winners-interview-2nd-place-keiichi-kuroyanagi-keiku/)]

For example, check out this latest Kaggle interview: [Airbnb New User Bookings, Winner's Interview: 2nd place, Keiichi Kuroyanagi (@Keiku)](http://blog.kaggle.com/2016/03/17/airbnb-new-user-bookings-winners-interview-2nd-place-keiichi-kuroyanagi-keiku/)

You can do Statistical Inference without advanced calculus. Even without formal math at all, if you're only interested in getting to know the subject.

* The 'G' in XGBT *does* stand for Gradient, so you'll eventually have to do some math, but why not just have fun starting out? You'll learn more, quicker!

**Other XGBT links:**

[Story and Lessons Behind the Evolution of XGBT](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~tqchen/2016/03/10/story-and-lessons-behind-the-evolution-of-xgboost.html)

[XGBT -- Let Us Learn From Its Author](http://www.slideshare.net/ShangxuanZhang/kaggle-winning-solution-xgboost-algorithm-let-us-learn-from-its-author)

Comment: *"not enough rep. to comment"* - and you're not going to gain more posting answers that you know aren't appropriate...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have indeed looked for such a course, and I found some, for example this one : http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/evolved/nnt1.html. The problem with those tutorials is that they usually don't use gradient descent (with is the main thing I have trouble with), but I would consider doing one of them if I don't succeed understanding by myself. What kind of advanced math do you think is needed ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thank you for your constructive input.

Comment: Thanks for the visualization, it's nice, even though I knew most of it. I am particularly interested in neural networks because of the nice things I have seen them do, generative neural networks that are able to compose music for example. I didn't know about the tree approach, thanks for mentioning it. If I understand correctly, those XGB trees are like constrained neural networks, which allows them to learn faster ?

Comment: Also, would it be right to say that neural networks are more appropriate than those trees when it is very hard to extract meaningful features ?

Comment: @sputnik Those are great questions, and they deserve to be treated as a separate post. I only brought up the Tree based models (in contrast to ANNs) because I wanted to give a simple example of machine learning which requires little math (if at all) for a first reading. If you're interested in comparing the more advanced methodologies, you'd have to go into more formal arguments, which will probably have mathematical underpinnings. (Not on this post...) If you're happy with my answer so far, please feel free to vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you audit the [Coursera course on Machine Learning taught by Andrew Ng](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning). It's very well structured and paced and he presents the math in a very comprehensible manner. If you can stick to it through Week 5, the work assignment is actually the very problem you're interested in: a neural network for hand-written digit recognition.